# Saving data in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Ok so I was wondering if it is possible to save like a variable in bash. I am writing a script where you build like farms and mines and I was just wondering if it is possible to bring back those variables even after I stopped the program and then got back on. So lets say I have built 4 farms farms would be farm=4, can I bring this variable back somehow? I know how to make a page that you can make a high scores list on (Which I did for a guessing game.), but this I don't know if it is possible in bash.

Comment: Why dont you consider writing the values in a file. Bash variables seems like a bad idea for the kind of thing you are doing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save all needed variables in a file (using *here-doc*):

```
cat<<EOF>/path/to/file
var1="$var1"
var2="$var2"
EOF
```

and to recreate your previous environment :

```
source /path/to/file
```

or

```
. /path/to/file
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

- the place where to put the *here-doc* depends of your code, can be the last lines if you don't have to save variables in loops by example
- the place to put the `source` command is the top of your script after the *shebang*

Help said :

```
$ LANG=C help source
```

> source: source filename [arguments]
>       Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
>
> ```
> Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
> entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
> If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
> when FILENAME is executed.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
> FILENAME cannot be read.
> ```

**NOTE**

if you want for some reasons to dynamically generate the files with pattern matching on variable names :

- by suffix : `printf '%q\n' $(set | grep "suffix=") > save_file`
- by prefix : `printf '%q\n' $(set | grep "^prefix") > save_file`

Thanks gniourf_gniourf for `printf` trick.

Comment: So I just put the second thing that in like the top of my script and file to the name of the place it in, correct? So it would be like this cat<<EOF>>/path/to/savefilename and this could be like a save button correct? and then you load with the second. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Ok what I am saying is I use cat<<EOF>>... as a save file. then I use source /path/to/file  as a loader is what I am taking from this

Comment: Added _NOTE_ for pattern matching on variables with prefix or suffix

Comment: well I have now tested it and I understand it now so thank you very much and I will actually probably use this later on too.

Comment: Added your printf trick with my solution. Your parameter expansion can't deal with suffix AFAIK, nor regex.

Comment: @sputnick sure it can't, but it's useless if you're careful with your variable names.

Answer (score 8):

You can write everything in a file in that format:

```
farm=4
myname=gniourf
```

And then source that file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Recover the saved states:
source file_where_i_saved_my_stuff

# Now you can recover all your variables!
echo "$farm"
echo "$myname"
```

---

## Edit

Since you want to know *how* you can save your variables, here's a quick hint, with a lot of stuff that hasn't been given in the other answer.

Alright, so you want to save some variables in a file, and be able to later source this file to recover the value of these variables. Of course, you'll have a lot of variables, and you don't want to explicitly write down the list of all the variables you'll have to save, which is error prone and retarded. I mean, nobody wants to do the following:

```
cat <<EOF > file_where_i_saved_my_stuff
variable1=$variable1
variable2=$variable2
...
variable1000000=$variable1000000
EOF
```

In fact, you don't want to do this at all for many reasons. Now, I'll address the solution:

The method relies on this stupid thing (together with good bash practice and knowledge): name all the variables you want to save using a prefix, e.g., `variable_i_want_to_save_`, so that you'll have variables like `variable_i_want_to_save_number_of_farms` and `variable_i_want_to_save_color_of_granny_dress` and so on. Do not use this prefix with variables you don't want to save.

### Smart thing #1

bash has a wonderful thing: you can get the name of all variables that start with a certain prefix like so:

```
"${!prefix@}"
```

This will expand to a list of all known variables that start with prefix `prefix`.

Hence, in our case,

```
for i in "${!variable_i_want_to_save_@}"; do
```

will loop through the name of all variables that are prefixed by our wonderful prefix. Isn't that great?

### Smart thing #2

If I am in the following situation:

```
a=1
b=2
variablename="a"
```

how do I get the value of the variable the name of which is the value of the variable `variablename`? Easy, use the `"${!variablename}"` construct. Look:

```
$ a=1
$ b=2
$ variablename=a
$ echo "${!variablename}"
1
```

The `${!prefix@}` and `${!variablename}` expansions are explained in the [*Shell Parameter Expansion* section of the Bash reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (you'll have to scroll down a bit to get there).

### (Broken) Solution

Then you're good for a broken solution to save your variables in a file, like so:

```
save_data_to_file() {
    for i in "${variable_i_want_to_save_@}"; do
        echo "$i=${!i}"
    done > file_where_i_saved_my_stuff
}
```

This is really efficient and cool, but really broken if you have spaces or junk characters of any sort in your variables (which can (and should) appear). Oh dear.

### Solution

The good thing for you is that bash has this wonderful `printf` command with its amazing format specification `%q` that will

> quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input

(I got this from `help printf`). It's amazing, it's absolutely fantastic, just try it:

```
$ a=$'bonjour les amis !\ncomment ça va ?'
$ # You see, variable a has a lot of stupid characters:
$ echo "$a"
bonjour les amis !
comment ça va ?
$ # and printf does a wonderful job:
$ printf '%s=%q\n' a "$a"
a=$'bonjour les amis!\ncomment \303\247a va ?'
```

You couldn't dream of something as good as this. Or maybe you could, but please just admit it's awesome!

So, here you are with your wonderful way to save your variables in a file:

```
save_data_to_file() {
    for i in "${!variable_i_want_to_save_@}"; do
        printf '%s=%q\n' "$i" "${!i}"
    done > file_where_i_saved_my_stuff
}
```

---

Note that sourcing an external file like this leads to obvious security issues, so make sure you only use this method with care!

Comment: yes but I would also need a save command which is what I was looking for more

Comment: Some great techniques, but (a) `"${prefix@}"` should be `"${!prefix@}"` (and so on throughout the rest of the post), and (b) it's worth pointing out the security risk that comes with sourcing an entire file, given that it won't just perform variable definitions, but execute whatever commands are  present.